# Maximum size of DataTable or other complex object in .NET

Tags: c#, memory

I know, that size of object is limited to 2GB in .NET,

but what about maximum size of more complex objects, like DataTable?

It depends on low-level objects inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More complex objects are still objects inside and they contain references to other objects. For example if this is `DataTable` then it contains references for earch row and so on. Each pointer would take 32 or 64 bit regarding of OS type. Only pointer sizes are sum and there is no limit for object graph depth (reasonable). The only limit you have in this case is max memory amount that can by allocated for the process itself.

Comment: Thanks. Thant enough for me. So theoretical limit in DataTable is size of `DataTable.Rows.ItemArray` object (or other simple object on last branch of that graph/tree), right?

Comment: Right. Theoretically 2Gb object could contain 17179869184 references. Reducing object data and non-reference items that it contains this number would be less. In case of `DataTable` it would be limited up to `int.MaxValue` that `DataRowCollection.Count Property` could store.

Answer (score 2):

regarding the rows he maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216.

Comment: Not answer, but useful. Thanks.